# multidimensional array sum and sorting

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$inventory = array(

   array("fruit"=>"orange", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"kiwi", "price"=>2),
   array("fruit"=>"apple", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"apple", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"apple", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"orange", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"banana", "price"=>10),
   array("fruit"=>"banana", "price"=>10),

);
```

// what I wish to do is loop through this array and add all of the 'prices' for each
// unique key  'fruit' and then sort them afterwards

//    ex. the output I wish to achieve would be an array as such:

```
$sum_array = array("banana"=>"20", "apple"=>"9", "orange"=>"6", "kiwi"=>"2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just group them by fruit and then sort the end-result:

```
function groupFruits(&$result, $item) 
{
    $key = $item['fruit'];
    @$result[$key] += $item['price'];

    return $result;
}

$grouped = array_reduce($inventory, 'groupFruits', array());

arsort($grouped);

print_r($grouped);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2Ffd4w)

See also: [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce)  [`arsort()`](http://php.net/arsort)

**Update**

You will see some crazy results when you look at this code in [different versions of PHP](http://3v4l.org/6QU3h).

Comment: Jack, Thanks

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION"

 
$inventory = array(

   array("fruit"=>"orange", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"kiwi", "price"=>2),
   array("fruit"=>"apple", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"apple", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"apple", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"orange", "price"=>3),
   array("fruit"=>"banana", "price"=>10),
   array("fruit"=>"banana", "price"=>10),

);

$grouped = array_reduce($inventory, function(&$result, $item) {
 @$result[$item['fruit']] += $item['price'];
 return $result;
}, array());

Comment: @CanadaPHP Updated the answer to work with older versions of php.

Comment: @CanadaPHP What do you mean *without* you rewriting? Rewrite what exactly?

Comment: your updated code generated an error
Warning: arsort() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer

Comment: @CanadaPHP I don't know what you mean, it runs fine [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MvtGKX).

Comment: @CanadaPHP Well, then you will have to do some debugging.

Comment: @CanadaPHP I didn't realize that `array_reduce()` introduced a mixed `$initial` since 5.3 .... if you can't upgrade you can just use a `foreach` and build `$grouped` inside that loop.

Comment: I am running version 5.2.17 and the answer generates an error